# Update product image label in Magento 1.9

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am trying to update the product image label. I wrote an observer to catch `catalog_product_save_before`.

The observer is catching the event and I am able echo/die from the function.

Here is the function to save the label.

```
    public function catalog_product_save_before($observer)
    {

//        $product = $observer->getProduct();
//        $product_id = $product->getId();

        $conn_write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
        if (isset($_POST['Media'])) {
            $post = $_POST['Media'];
            foreach ($post as $value_id => $item) {
                $sql = "UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value SET `label` = '" . addslashes($item['label']) . "' WHERE  value_id = " . (int)$value_id;
                if (isset($item['position'])) {
                    $sql = "UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value SET `label` = '" . addslashes($item['label']) . "', `position` = " . (int)$item['position'] . " WHERE  value_id = " . (int)$value_id;
                }
                $conn_write->query($sql);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Here is an echo of the $sql

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value SET `label` = 'Test Label Text' WHERE value_id = 8441
```

When I run this in Workbench the label is updated,
also when I run _test.php it's updated as well.?

_test.php:

```
require_once "app/Mage.php";
Mage::app();
$conn_write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$item = ['label'=>'123456798'];
$value_id = 8441;

$sql = "UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value SET `label` = '" . addslashes($item['label']) . "' WHERE  value_id = " . (int)$value_id;
$conn_write->query($sql);

die("COMPLETE");
```

Can someone shed some light as to why the row is not allowed to be updated?

Is there a way to get some feedback from MySQL?

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark the issue as solved. To do this, the best approach is to create an answer, and self-accept (by clicking the tick mark). We prefer answers not to be merged into questions here (unless it is unavoidable because they have been closed). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP.)*

The mystery has been solved... phew.

Use `catalog_product_save_after` not before, must override the info on save otherwise.